# ORDER BY two columns if duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a simple query:

```
create table #Test
(
    ID  INT,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    num INT
)

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(1,'bob', 98)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(2,'bob', 44)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(3,'sam', 60)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(4,'deacon', 14)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(5,'toby', 99)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(6,'toby', 12)

SELECT * FROM #Test ORDER BY num DESC, name DESC

DROP TABLE #Test
```

This outputs:

```
ID  name    num
5   toby    99
1   bob     98
3   sam     60
2   bob     44
4   deacon  14
6   toby    12
```

What I am trying to do is sort the data first by num BUT if there are duplicate names, I would like the names following eachother, no matter what the num is.

The output I am looking for would be:

```
ID   name    num
5     toby    99
6     toby    12
1     bob     98
2     bob     44
3     sam     60
4     deacon  14
```

I am having issues with my ORDER BY, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  t.ID,
  t.name,
  t.num
FROM
  #Test t
ORDER BY
  (
   SELECT
     MAX(t2.num)
   FROM
     #test t2
   WHERE
     t2.NAME = t.name
   GROUP BY
     t2.NAME
  ) DESC
```

Comment: This is getting really close. only weird thing is that the first two records are ordered opposite compared to all the others. The first two records are ascending, while the rest are descending.

Comment: Are you sure? When I run it, it is identical to your required output.

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to get your expected output because it's not alphabetic, but I think this is what you are looking for. (swap **name** and **num** in Order by)

```
create table #Test
(
    ID  INT,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    num INT
)

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(1,'bob', 98)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(2,'bob', 44)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(3,'sam', 60)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(4,'deacon', 14)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(5,'toby', 99)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES(6,'toby', 12)

SELECT * FROM #Test ORDER BY name DESC, num DESC

DROP TABLE #Test
```

Comment: It has to first order by num. If the name of toby was adam or something, he would show up at the very end. My issue is still there

Comment: +1 Also, don't use `SELECT * FROM table`, it makes your DB sluggish.

Answer (score 0):

First get the names of the top scores. We do this with the subquery.

Then using that subquery, get order of the names with the highest and then sort by names then num

```
select * from
 (
select name as cname,max(num) as num from test
group by name, order by max(num) num desc
) as x
order by cname desc, num desc
```

Comment: looks promising, just get an error stating there is a syntax error near order?

Comment: Can MySQL do subqueries? I was under the impression that it didn't do them, but it's been a while since I've looked at it.

Comment: Not too sure honestly, just trying to play around with this query